# Property set on first button press and does not change on subsequent press

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties

I have created a ViewController containing one picker. Its view is triggered to appear and populate the picker with one of four data arrays, depending on which one of four buttons has been pressed in the superview. I gave the subview an `int` property called `pickerType`, which I then set within the button code, like so:

```
    - (IBAction)chooseDepType:(id)sender
    {

        if (pickerView==nil)
        {
           pickerView = [[Picker alloc] initWithNibName:@"Picker" bundle:nil];
           //send message to next view telling which array to load in picker
           pickerView.pickerType=1;
        }
        [self.view addSubview:pickerView.view];
    }
```

The other button methods look the same, except that the `pickerType` is set to a different value.
Then, in the subview, I set up the datasource and delegate methods like so:

```
   -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
    {
        if(pickerType_ ==1)
        {
            // return the appropriate number of components, for instance
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that even though I am setting `pickerView` to a new value in each button's code, my subview is not recognizing that the value has changed. Basically, no matter which button I press, it shows me a picker filled with the data corresponding to the *first* button I pressed. To complicate matters, perhaps, the superview is a Detail view in a Master-Detail template.

`pickerType` property is created like this:

```
    @property (assign) int pickerType;

    @synthesize pickerType=pickerType_;
```

I am using ARC. I don't know if this is a dumb programming error on my part, or has something to do with the lifecycle of a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are checking whether your `Picker` has already been created:

```
if (pickerView==nil)
```

before setting the type:

```
    pickerView.pickerType=1;
```

the next time you press a button, `pickerView` already exists, execution skips over the body of the `if` and the type is not changed.

To fix this, move the type-setting statement out of the `if` block.

Incidentally, if you have four buttons that all do almost exactly the same thing, you can have them all trigger the same `IBAction` and distinguish which was pressed by their `tag` properties:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker: (id)sender
{
    if (pickerView==nil)
    {
       pickerView = [[Picker alloc] initWithNibName:@"Picker" bundle:nil];
    }
    // Each button's tag could correspond exactly to the appropriate pickerType,
    // or have any other meaning you choose.
    [pickerView setPickerType:[sender tag]];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView.view];
}
```

Comment: I should have said that I did try removing the nil check, and it still didn't work. But I was trying so many different things that I might have screwed up somewhere. I will try again. I also like your alternate suggestion. Will report back when I've tried this.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks. Removing my nil check didn't work previously because I had also moved my instantiation of the picker view up into viewDidLoad. I'm left wondering, though, why do I have to re-instantiate the picker view each time I want one of its properties set to a different value (ie., inside the code for each button)? It doesn't work if I don't.

Answer (score 0):

If `pickerView` is not nil then all you are doing is making its view a subview of the current controller (which it already is if no other code has removed it), without changing a property.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call [pickerView reloadAllComponents] after assign new type;